# All that anyone could be

Tags: phrase-meaning

The following passage is quoted from Virginia Woolf's suicide note to her husband.  What exactly does the phrase "all that anyone could be" mean?

> You have given me the greatest possible happiness. You have been in every way  all that anyone could be. I don't think two people could have been happier till this disease came.

Does that sentence mean "You have been everything to me in every way possible"?

Comment: *all that anyone could be* means exactly what it says: no one could ever be more than you have been, in every way.

Comment: "everything that one could hope for" says something very similar.  The way in the quote emphasizes a span of things and a thoroughness above and beyond 'hope' in some ways.

Answer (score 2):

She means that he was a good husband, lover, friend, supporter, cook, confidant, traveling companion, business manager - or whatever "all" and "in every way" means in her case as well as in her mind.

She also means that no other man could have been an improvement on him in any of those areas.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe she meant that he did for her what a human being on any planet could ever do; **other than God Himself.**